# Solving dynamic mathematical formula with nested parentheses in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mathematical-expressions

I am having saving dynamic mathematical formula as string. I have two predefined functions like `avg(A,B)` and `best_of(1,A,B)`.The formula can consist of any mathematical operator, with nested parenthesis.

How do I execute the formula in ruby. The following are few formula formats,

```
avg(A,B,C)+D

best_of(1,A,B,C)+avg(D,E)

avg(best_of(1,A,B)+C+D)+E
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I would want to execute the formula, given that A,B,C have values and return the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a parser for your expressions. Take a look at [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) or [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/).

Or take a look at an existing math expression parser like [Dentaku](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku) where you can supply custom functions.